# Where should my application setting be in a .Net Core / EF Core class library project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am trying to store my database connection string in a config file so that I can change it depending on the deployment environment. My data access is using EF Core 1.1.0.

I have looked at some full .Net applications that use EF Core and use App.config to store and retrieve the connection string like this:

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorks"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

However, when I try that approach in my .Net Core class library project by creating the same App.config file, when I hit the above line of code I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.

So my question is.. Where should these settings be stored in a .Net Core class library project and how are they then retrieved? Should it be App.config, project.json, appsettings.json or some other file??

Comment: Most common approach would be to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` with JSON files. See [this article](http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects) on how to use it regardless of project type.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i look at this :

[Entity Framework Core 1.0 Connection Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982387/entity-framework-core-1-0-connection-strings)

I think he used Json. Said it was easier, and managed to answer himself. Make sure your files see each other and it should be ok. Sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very similar scenario to the one I was trying to achieve.

Another 'Gotcha' in my development scenario was that the app.config needs to be in the consuming applications folder structure, not the class library's folder structure.